# Convert .tex to .tex, but replace \ref{} with actual numbers

Tags: compiling

I use Pandoc a lot to go between .tex, .markdown, and .docx. Everything works well enough for me in the .tex to .docx conversion, but the table and section references show `\ref{my_label}` rather than the actual table or section number.

Is there a way to convert a .tex file with labels and references to a .tex file with all of those replaced?

Say my MWE is this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{One} \label{sec:one}

I need to right some more in Section \ref{sec:one}.

\end{document}
```

Can I turn it into this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{One} \label{sec:one}

I need to right some more in Section 1.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yo can do it manually but it is not recommended at all, you loose automation and increase the risk of mistakes. Perhaps the only thing you need is to compile a couple of times more the `.tex` file to get a pdf with references listed correctly.

Comment: This is like 'I want to shoot myself into my foot', since at that point you will change your `*.tex` document, e.g. adding a section, an equation etc. all references change.

Comment: I agree this is an odd request. But this is easier than converting some people to LaTeX (usually impossible) and would allow me to generate a .docx that other could edit. If it can't be done, then it can't be done.

Comment: You might take a look at [`latex2rtf`](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/) instead of Pandoc. I'm not sure  of the full list of things you need support for, but I just used `latex2rtf` on a small test file and it does write the cross-references correctly.

Comment: @PaulGessler -- Thanks. I've used latex2rtf before. In general I prefer Pandoc, but latex2rtf may be my best option for this. Thanks.

Comment: I usually use `tex4ht` but it is not unproblematic. It *alters* references but it does mostly map them to Word/LibreOffice fields, which is not terrible. (It makes more of a mess of the bibliography.) I have to go through removing the 'on page ...' it adds to each 'section ...', though.